# Efficient way to ensure unique rows in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `UNIQUE` index on the column(s) that has/have to be unique.

Quoting the [`CREATE INDEX`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) manual page :

> If the `UNIQUE` keyword appears between
>   `CREATE` and `INDEX` then duplicate index
>   entries are not allowed. 
> Any attempt
>   to insert a duplicate entry will
>   result in an error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `unique` column constraint

http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint

Answer (score 0):

UNIQUE prevents non-unique rows; if you already have duplicates, looking at [SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) may help.